# Octothorpe (hashtag) after page URL to change input button default

Tags: javascript, html

Here's an example, I have a form  with radio buttons with the first being checked by default:

```
<input type=radio name="input" id="one" checked>
<input type=radio name="input" id="two">
<input type=radio name="input" id="three">
<input type=radio name="input" id="four">
```

When I type index.html#two, how do I get it to automatically check two by default instead of one, and when I don't have any octothorpe it'll default to the first?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is only possible with javascript. I dont know how exaclty, but should be easly done with JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but if it doesn't work, the annotations will hopefully get you to the right spot

```
window.onload = function() {
        if(location.hash){//if the page's URL has an octothore part
            document.getElementById(location.hash.substr(1)).checked=true;
            //gets the checkbox's ID with the hash minus the octothorpe, and then checks it
        } else {
            //if there WASN't an octorthorpe
            document.getElementById('one').checked=true;
        }
    };
```

If you wanted to maintain the state:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    window.onload = function() {
        if(location.hash){//if the page's URL has an octothore part
            document.getElementById(location.hash.substr(1)).checked=true;
            //gets the checkbox's ID with the hash minus the octothorpe, and then checks it
        } else {
            //if there WASN't an octorthorpe
            document.getElementById('one').checked=true;
        }
    };
},50);
```

Whenever you want it to stop, you can use `interval.clear();`

Though for code hygiene, I would suggest:

```
var checkBoxBasedOnHash = function() {
    if(location.hash){//if the page's URL has an octothore part
        document.getElementById(location.hash.substr(1)).checked=true;
        //gets the checkbox's ID with the hash minus the octothorpe, and then checks it
    } else {
        //if there WASN't an octorthorpe
        document.getElementById('one').checked=true;
    }
};
window.onload = function() {
    checkBoxBasedOnHash();
    var interval = setInterval(checkBoxBasedOnHash,500);
}
```

because it cuts down on duplicate code and makes positive that the interval only occurs after the checkboxes have been loaded.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. (An answer acceptance would still be nice though :P)

Comment: Also, is there any way for the script to see if the hashtag changes without reloading the page? Perhaps with the function on a timer? (though I'd like a less resource intensive way of this)

Comment: I don't believe there is one without importing some huge library for that one tiny little task, though `setInterval` is perfect for this kind of thing

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example please? I don't seem to be able to get setInterval to work properly.

Comment: The second doesn't appear to update when the hashtag changes, and the third doesn't seem to see the hashtag at all

Comment: Nevermind, when I use the third I can't select any other checkboxes or it'll automatically change back to the one indicated by the hashtag, still the same problem with the second

Comment: What do you want it to do when it changes?

Comment: I would like to be able to click on any checkbox after the page is loaded and for it to stay on that checkbox until the hashtag is changed

Comment: I looked back into it, and such a thing apparently *does* exist https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Htqfw/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="input" id="one" />
<input type="radio" name="input" id="two" />
<input type="radio" name="input" id="three" />
<input type="radio" name="input" id="four" />
```

JS (requires jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Grab the hash from the URL
    var hash = location.hash;

    // Uncheck all the radio buttons
    $("input").attr("checked", null);

    // If there's a hash, check the matching radio button
    if (hash) {
        $("input" + hash).attr("checked", "checked");   
    }

    // If there's not, check the first radio button
    else {
        $("#one").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});
```

To test this in jsfiddle, replace `location.hash` with a string to pretend you're grabbing the hash from the URL, e.g.:

```
var hash = "#three";
```